# IronSource Mediation ads stopped working after uploading to the playstore

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I have a good running app which contains the IronSource Mediation SDK.
I decided to add AdMob to the mediation and implemented it in my sourcecode, on the test device everything works fine, sometimes it displays Admob ads, sometimes other networks (like it should be)
But as soon as I sign the APK and upload it to the playstore nothing works, no ads are displayedm, not even from the IronSource network.
Before I added AdMob everything worked fine.

I'm getting many bad reviews because the user cannot watch a rewarded video ad to get his ingame currency.

I contacted the support but that will take some time until they answer so I'm asking here to hopefuly get a faster answer.

Kind regards